# Python: raise Exception if file with name "foobar" gets opened

Tags: python, debugging

I have a huge code base before me, and I have a place where a file with name "foobar" gets written.

I have no clue where this file gets read.

My idea how to solve this:

1. do monkey patching or mocking. An exceptions should get raised if a file with this name gets opened.
2. run all tests and see where the exception gets raised.

How to let the interpreter raise an exception if a file with given name gets opened?

I am sure that the place I search is pure python, not a c-extension.

I use Python 2.7

Comment: Can you remove or rename the file?

Comment: @internet_user yes I could, but this does not help to debug this, since I guess the reading part is listing the directory first. No exception will happen since the directory is empty and that's ok in this context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can override (shadow) builtin open function. Add this in your main module:

```
import __builtin__

open_file = __builtin__.open

def fake_open(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    if filename == 'foobar':
        raise Exception('foobar filename')
    else:
        return open_file(filename, *args, **kwargs)

__builtin__.open = fake_open
```

Comment: With this answer I found the corresponding open()  in 106k Python source code lines in seconds. Thank you!

Comment: @guettli same way, i think, `open` in io module can be shadowed: `open_io_file = io.open; def fake_io_open(): # same logic; io.open = fake_io_open`